# Making the files outputted using PhP open in a new tab/window

Tags: php, html

I am using **php** to output a list of files from a directory on my local drive. I also use an 'onChange' html select function to open the files when selected.

When selected the files either download (if it is a word or similar document) or open up in the same tab - which means the user has to press the browser's back button to get back onto the site.

Here is my code at the moment:

**List.php**

```
<div align="center">
<form name="list">
<select name="menu" onChange="top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO" id="marketinglist">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>

  <?php 
       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/policies/one/*') as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='policies/one/" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
</form>
</div>
```

I have tried adding `target="_blank"` to the html select tags but this did nothing (Probably because it is an attribute to the `<a>` tag).

Can anyone suggest another way to do this?

Thanks for reading

Comment: [window.open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) might be the thing you are looking for `onchange = window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,"_blank")`

Comment: You can simply turn the text of the select options into links (so element of type `<a>`) and use the `target="blank"` property in there.

Comment: I've tried adding an <a> tag and target="_blank" and it still just opens in the same window/tab.

Comment: @TanuelMategi I've tried your method and this doesn't load the file at all, not even in the current screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in the comments - `window.open()` is what you are looking for.

Edit your `<select>` tag to look like this:

```
<select name="menu" onChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank')" id="marketinglist">
```

And all your problems will be solved.